# How to use iterator pattern to traverse the object structure designed in Composition Pattern

Tags: java, algorithm, design-patterns

I was reading "**Head First Design Pattern**" and now I got stuck in some of the code in Composition Pattern,on page 369. The structure is designed in composition pattern and traversed through iterator pattern.

The core algorithm code of CompositeIterator is:

```
public boolean hasNext() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (itemStack.size() == 0) {
        return false;
    } else {
        Iterator<MenuComponent> iter = itemStack.peek();
        if (!iter.hasNext()) {
            itemStack.pop();
            return hasNext();
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
public MenuComponent next() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (hasNext()) {
        Iterator<MenuComponent> iter = this.itemStack.peek();
        MenuComponent mc = iter.next();
        if (mc instanceof Menu) {
            itemStack.push(mc.createIterator());
        }
        return mc;
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Here is the print function:

```
public void printAll(){
    Iterator<MenuComponent> iter=menus.createIterator();
    while(iter.hasNext()){
        MenuComponent mc=iter.next();
        System.out.println(mc.getName()+" "+mc.getDescription());
    }
}
```

And here is main function with code:

```
    Menu m1 = new Menu("aaa", "a");
    Menu m2 = new Menu("bbb", "b");
    Menu m3 = new Menu("ccc", "c");

    Menu all=new Menu("all", "all");
    all.add(m1);
    m1.add(m2);
    m2.add(m3);
    Waitress w=new Waitress(all);
    w.printAll();
```

When I try to print all of them,the result would be like this:

`a aaa`

`b bbb`

`c ccc`

`c ccc`

It seems like the iterator just ignored the allmenu item and print m3 twice...Why did it happen?  What's the matter with my code... Did I just get wrong with the recursive algorithm?
Thanks

Comment: Shouldn't you add `m2` and `m3` to `all`? Also, could you show us the code which prints the menu?

Comment: hi,@Nebelmann, the book shows the code like what you said... but I supposed it should be useful universally...not matter how the structure is. I just changed the structure.